# Find length by subsetting or using %in%

Tags: r

I have a data.frame "df":

```
df

  id.number         names
1        102  Program ID 1
2        102  Program ID 1
3         11  Program ID 1
4         11  Program ID 1
5       1293  Program ID 1
6       1293  Program ID 1
7        132  Program ID 1
8        143  Program ID 1
9        143  Program ID 1
10       143  Program ID 1
11       143 Program ID 22
12       143 Program ID 22
13       143 Program ID 22
14       155 Program ID 22
15       155 Program ID 22
16      1552 Program ID 22
17      1553 Program ID 22
```

And vector: `name_1 <- "Program ID 1"`

Now I would like to find the unique length of "id.number" by "Program ID 1" and by matching with vector `"name_1"`.
I can find the unique length of "id.number" by "Program ID 1" with

```
length(unique(id.number[names=="Program ID 1"]))
```

But I would like to find unique length by matching my vector with column "names" in the data.frame "df".

So I need (and would like) to use something like that:

```
length(unique(subset(....)
```

or

```
length(unique(subset .... %in% names_1
```

And my output should be the unique length/(number) in column "id.number" and  **not** `data table` **nor** `list`.

Desired Output:
 just number, and in my case this is: **5** 
which is also the result of code `length(unique(id.number[names=="Program ID 1"])).`

Comment: Can you show us your desired output too please?

Comment: Try `library(data.table);setDT(df)[, uniqueN(id.number), names]`

Comment: Output should be just number, and in my case this is: 5 which is also the result of code length(unique(id.number[names=="Program ID 1"])).

Comment: Using the code I used, it gets `setDT(df)[, uniqueN(id.number), names]$V1#
[1] 5 4`  I assume that you want to do this for all the `names` rather than a single one

Comment: I get: could not find function "uniqueN" and if I do this setDT(df)[, unique(id.number), names]$name_1 i ger NULL

Comment: I might be stating the obvious here, but isn't `with(df, length(unique(id.number[names%in%name_1])))` simply what you are looking for?

Comment: It is from the devel version.  But you can change the code to `length(unique(id.number))` Anyway, it looks like you are just after a single value.

Comment: @Akrun, I am after the single value but matching by one vector. And thank you also for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comments, you just need to wrap your code that worked on vectors into a `with(df, ...)` statement:

```
with(df, length(unique(id.number[names=="Program ID 1"])))
```

Or to generalize to cases when `name_1` contains several names:

```
with(df, length(unique(id.number[names%in%name_1])))
```